# How can set up my Vue.js site to clear the browser's Javascript console on every hot reload event?

Tags: vue.js, webpack-hmr, hot-module-replacement, webpack-dev-middleware

I have a Vue.js site with Webpack Dev Middleware (served via an ASP.NET Core site by HTTP.sys web server, though I'm guessing that doesn't matter). Does anyone know how I can set up my site to clear the browser's Javascript console on every hot reload event?

Here's [the only related link](https://github.com/webpack/webpack-dev-server/issues/565) I can find, but it seems to be for a web server I am not using.  I'm not sure why the particular web server would matter.

Comment: call `console.clear()` in your `created`?

Comment: On the root component, you mean?  Created doesn't run on every HMR, only ones that result in the component being re-created.  Still, better than nothing.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

In my main app .js file:

```
if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept() // already had this init code 

    module.hot.addStatusHandler(status => {
        if (status === 'prepare') console.clear()
    })
}
```

That got it to work consistently for me.

See also https://webpack.js.org/api/hot-module-replacement/#addstatushandler .

Answer (score 11):

your link contains the response for your question. Just add in your `main.js` file:

```
window.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
  if (e.data && typeof e.data === 'string' && e.data.match(/webpackHotUpdate/)) {
    console.log('hot reload happened')
    console.clear()
  }
})
```

Example of a complete main.js file:

```
import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import router from './router'
import store from './store'

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  router,
  store,
  render: h => h(App)
}).$mount('#app')

window.addEventListener('message', (e) => {
  if (e.data && typeof e.data === 'string' && e.data.match(/webpackHotUpdate/)) {
    console.log('hot reload happened')
    console.clear()
  }
})
```

EDIT: I didn't read your answers to the github issue. Could you provide some kind of `JSON.stringify(e)` on your event message on multiple events so we can check what you have?

Comment: What happens when you `console.log(e instanceof MessageEvent)`? Indeed when I `JSON.stringify(e)` I have only `{"isTrusted":true}` but when I `JSON.stringify(e.data)` I have all sorts of data

Comment: Hmm, looks like I had the code in the wrong place before?  Not sure.  Anyway, trying again, I get the following JSON in `e.data.payload.payload` on a HMR event: https://jsfiddle.net/szal/qp8rojng/ - no "webpackHotUpdate" in there, and I see nothing to distinguish a HMR event from other events where`e.data.payload.event === 'flush'`.

Comment: Good idea, we seem closer.  Any further ideas?

Comment: All right, so this is just one message that you receive, are you sure you don't receive other messages? I just want to make it sure. In my case, `e.data` is just a string when Hot Reload happens but I also have the kind of message you pasted in the fiddle sometimes

Comment: Yes, I don't receive other events here.  

I think I figured it out; see my answer.  Thanks for prompting additional thoughts.