# Is there a way of printing on the browser console when React Fast Refresh finishes refreshing?

Tags: reactjs, webpack-hmr, react-refresh

I tried to search here/Google/GitHub but I'm not even sure of how to look for this. No matter what words I use they will always show me results of how to implement HMR. But that's not my issue. I just want to print on the browser console when the React Fast Refresh (Hot Module Reload) refreshes so I know that it was updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay. After searching for something different, I managed to find exactly what I wanted.

Instead of looking for "how to print when hmr refreshes" I searched for "how to clear console when hmr refreshes" and I found this:

https://stackoverflow.com/a/53933757/12038349

```
if (module.hot) {
    module.hot.accept() // you don't need this if you're using CRA

    module.hot.addStatusHandler(status => {
        if (status === 'prepare') console.clear()
    })
}
```

Worked like a charm.